# Reverse The Odd Words in the sentence

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse the odd words in the sentence. Its working fine. But its appending undefined in the front.

```
var str = "get busy living or get busy dying.";
var newstr = str.split(" "), result;

for(i=0;i<newstr.length;i++){
    if(i%2 !== 0){            
        result += newstr[i].split("").reverse().join("");
        result += ' '; 
    } else {              
        result += newstr[i];
        result += ' ';
    }
}
```

Output is

```
   undefinedget ysub living ro get ysub dying.
```

Can some one point me where i am going wrong!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not initializing `result`, so the first `+=` adds something to an undefined value.

Just declare and initialize `result`:

```
var result = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it more concisely:

```js
var str = "get busy living or get busy dying.";
var result = str.split(" ").map(function(word, i) {
  return i % 2 == 0 ? word : word.split("").reverse().join(""); }).join(" ");

alert(result);
```